# How to put inner window function in a sub-query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to sum the output of a window function. The problem is, it raises an error when I try and do the below...

```
SELECT 
    cm.cust_id,
    SUM(SUM(tr.FD_sales) OVER (partition by cm.cust_id order by tr.event_date range between interval 7 days preceding and current row)) AS T
FROM   
    campaign_engagement_history cm 
    LEFT JOIN 
    transactions_filtered tr ON cm.cust_id == tr.cust_id 
    AND DATE(tr.EVENT_DATE) BETWEEN DATE(date_add(cm.campaign_send_date, -90)) AND DATE(cm.campaign_send_date)   
GROUP BY
    cm.cust_id
```

Does anyone have any advice as to how to solve this problem? I don't know what having a window function inside a sub-query would look like

This is the error:

```
It is not allowed to use a window function inside an aggregate function. Please use the inner window function in a sub-query.
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

First select the query with window function then wrap it with a outer function to have sum on the value of window function with group by clause:

```
select cust_id,sum(T) from 
(
    SELECT 
        cm.cust_id,
        SUM(tr.FD_sales) OVER (partition by cm.cust_id order by tr.event_date range between interval 7 days preceding and current row) AS T
    FROM   
        campaign_engagement_history cm 
        LEFT JOIN 
        transactions_filtered tr ON cm.cust_id == tr.cust_id 
        AND DATE(tr.EVENT_DATE) BETWEEN DATE(date_add(cm.campaign_send_date, -90)) AND DATE(cm.campaign_send_date)   
) t
GROUP BY
    cust_id
```

Comment: @Sam Comber Have you tried this? Please let me know if you face any more difficulties.